# raspbian-buster lite and debian asuswrt

Tags: linux, networking, asus, asuswrt

so I am running into a weird situation where ping6 google.com works, ping4 google.com doesn't, on eth, on wifi both work. This just started after upgrading my router firmware(Asus RT-AC68R from RT-AC68R_3.0.0.4_386_41634-g08f88ae to RT-AC68R_3.0.0.4_386_43129-g60defb2) I have the pi setup with as pihole and rarely make changes both wifi and eth are set to have static ip from router through router interface(not configured on pi). Also to be clear its not a dns problem ping4 8.8.8.8 doesn't work, ping6 2607:f8b0:4008:800::200e does. also ping4 10.0.0.5 does work.(seems to be only ipv4 connection past router that don't work)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:0c:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.8/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2601:*edited* scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 597sec preferred_lft 597sec
    inet6 fe80::f838:5e31:e58e:fc7a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::f838:5e31:e58e:fc7a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2601:*edited*  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:0c:c8:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 377402  bytes 107051612 (102.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87373  bytes 11165082 (10.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

nslookup google.com

Server:         127.0.0.1

Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:

Name:   google.com

Address: 142.250.64.142

Name:   google.com

Address: 2607:f8b0:4008:80e::200e
```

All this just adds more to the confusion as it seems I can nslookup just fine but cant ping, though dns is setup with pihole 127.0.0.1#53 is setup to use unbound 127.0.0.1#5353 which is setup to use ipv4 and ipv6 so could just be working through ipv6. However still why is wifi working 100% but not eth again having not changed anything in about a month.

Edit: I have also now tried a fresh pi image from usb and it has this issue as well so seems its not a client issue.
removing static assignment on router had no effect.

```
edit temp fix:
broken setup:
on device eth0 set to static on router devices eth0 and wlan0 set to static ip
working setup:
on device eth0 set to dhcp on router eth0/wlan0 set to auto

static was setup in /etc/dhcpd.conf as follows
interface eth0
        static ip_address=10.0.0.8/24
        static routers=10.0.0.1
        static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1

dhcpcd --version
dhcpcd 8.1.2
maybe an incompatibility with dhcp server on router and this old dhcpd version?
```

```
edit99: so it would appear that what ever 
ip I set in the routers wan dns that device stops working
setting it to cloudflare all devices are working again.
```

Answer (score 0):

short:
so it would appear that what ever
ip I set in the routers wan dns that device stops working
setting it to cloudflare all devices are working again.

upgrading my router firmwareAsus RT-AC68R from RT-AC68R_3.0.0.4_386_41634-g08f88ae to RT-AC68R_3.0.0.4_386_43129-g60defb2

long:
I have two debian machines running pihole + unbound and either one I put in for wan dns that device stops working on ipv4(can ping6 any device/domain/etc, can only ping4 local devices) setting it to cloudflare(or im guessing anything not local) ipv4 on those two start working again. Lan and IPv6 the whole time are set to either of the debian pihole + unbound setups and work fine. However since even though I am setting up different dns the firmware still send the routers ipv6 address for dns and ipv4 dns2 address so the setup then bypasses the pihole dns and uses cloudlfare.